# Can I get any value of annotation, without annotation`s name?

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to write a method that returned the value of the annotation method.

I tried to use this variants, nothing succeeded

Params:

- clazz - Сlass that has annotations
- annotationClazz - My Annotation.class
- parametersName - method`s name

This is my code:

```
public static Object getAnnotationValue(Class clazz, Class annotationClazz, String parametersName) {

    Annotation an = clazz.getAnnotation(annotationClazz);
    if (an.equals(null)) {
        throw new CoreError("Класс " + clazz + " не содержит аннотацию " + annotationClazz);
    }
    PageName pn = (PageName) an;

    try {
        //its working!
        System.out.println(pn.value());

        //not working :(
        System.out.println(an.getClass().getMethod(parametersName).getDefaultValue()); //not working :(
        System.out.println(an.annotationType().getDeclaredMethod(parametersName, annotationClazz).getDefaultValue());
        System.out.println(pn.getClass().getMethod(parametersName).getDefaultValue());
        System.out.println(pn.annotationType().getDeclaredMethod(parametersName, annotationClazz).getDefaultValue());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code keeps looking for the *default* value, but your question never mentions if the default value exists. To get the provided value, you must `invoke` the method on an instance.

Besides, you're using `getMethod` and `getDeclaredMethod` wrong in most cases.

Here's a working example:

```
public static Object getAnnotationValue(Class clazz, Class annotationClazz, String parameterName) {

    Annotation an = clazz.getAnnotation(annotationClazz);
    System.out.println(an.annotationType().getMethod(parameterName).invoke(an));
}
```

So for a class like:

```
@PageName("testPage") //Same as @PageName(value = "testPage")
public class Example {}
```

calling

```
getAnnotationValue(Example.class, PageName.class, "value")
```

would print

> testPage

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know about "invoke".
This is what i need!